# How to get access to the model in the view - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, domain-object

I have the following model:

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    function __Construct( $name )
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

I have the following controller:

```
class NavigationController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $people = array(
            new Person("James"),
            new Person("Bob")
        );
        return $this->render('FrameworkBundle:Navigation:index.html.php', $people);
    }
}
```

How do I get access to the model array in the view. Is there a way to access the model directly or do I have to assign a property like so:?

```
class NavigationController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $people = array(
            new Person("James"),
            new Person("Bob")
        );
        return $this->render('FrameworkBundle:Navigation:index.html.php', array( "model" => $people ) );
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php 
    foreach( $model as $person )
    {
       echo $person->title;
    }
?>
```

The problem with the above will be that it can be changed by a user to

```
return $this->render( 'FrameworkBundle:Navigation:index.html.php', array( "marybloomingpoppin" => $people ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

With the example view you used, you already had the correct implementation:

```
class NavigationController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $people = array(
            new Person("James"),
            new Person("Bob")
        );
        return $this->render('FrameworkBundle:Navigation:index.html.php', array( "model" => $people ) );
    }
}
```

You mentioned the concern that somebody could change the assignment in the controller, but this is something you always have if somebody changes the name of a variable only in one place and not in all. So I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately my experience of changing variables extends far past this. I had called some array( "people" => $people ).. And another colleague did this with array( "users" => $peopleRepository ). When it came to the third colleague, he was utterly confused for the 2 weeks I was on holiday because this variable was different in the view (was there a separate model he was missing?) (this had happened across the entire application)... In C#.NET MVC (although you have a viewbag) everything is access by @model in the view and is to the best of its ability, not a confusion!

Comment: This is then not a technical question but a matter of taste and naming convention. I usually give lists of entities the plural name of my entity, so if I have an array of Users I call it array('users' => $whateverVariable) so that at least in the view the acces to a List of users is always the same.

Comment: @moc it's a programming question... I don't know how to do it another way, what's the code. I don't have a care about naming conventions, I didn't ask if it was a better way, I asked how to do it. this is completely a programming question.

Comment: Then I unfortunately don't understand the question. Because the code that should work was already provided by you. And that is what I tried to pointed out. Besides that I don't understand the question :(